# Convert strings with format `09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016` to date

Tags: r, date, parsing

I am on MacOS. I have difficulties parsing a date string like the one below:

```
"09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016"
```

I tried generating such a format:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", 'en_US.UTF-8')   # set locale to EN
f <- "%I:%M %p - %a %b-%m-%Y"             # define format
z <- format(Sys.time(), format=f)         # get example
z
> "09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016"
```

and parsing it, but it does not work.

```
> strftime(z, format = f)
Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz = tz) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> strptime(z, format = f)
[1] NA
```

**How can I parse a string with the described format?**

Comment: have you tried this one? : library(anytime) :

anydate("09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016")

Comment: @MFR `anydate("09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016") [1] NA`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", 'C')
f <- "%I:%M %p - %a %b-%d-%Y"
strptime("09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016", format = f, tz = "GMT")
#[1] "2016-10-10 09:12:00 GMT"
```

`10` is not the month but the day.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try 'lubridate':

```
require(lubridate)
> parse_date_time("09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016", "HMmdY")
[1] "2016-10-10 09:12:00 UTC"
```

Comment: wow, `parse_date_time` seems pretty smart in identifying the needed information and discarding the rest...

Comment: actually I had some dirty data, like `"09:12 AM - Mon Oct-10-2016 (some text info here)"`. Amazing. `parse_date_time ` also handles this, making the cleaning step obsolete in my case.

Comment: note that for AM/PM format it should be `"IMpmdY"` instead of `"HMmdY" `.